# Where is coming Margin Top?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular5

I just started Angular 5 development with my knowledge of HTML and css.

Right now I am making a frondend template with the help of components.

I dont get any idea that a margin top **111.81** is coming ?

[image]

Comment: may be this is coming due to H2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be caused by your h2 (try setting line-height: 0;) or check your styles.css file at the root of your app to see if there is a padding.

Answer (score 0):

ADD the CSS ::

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {margin: 0px;}
```

Comment: I gave the margin for h2 and its now having the margin of 72 for body and  h2 1301*27  now